# Datalist is broken when populating a (mostly) unrelated element

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, datalist

TL;DR: I have no idea why this is broken in Chrome, but any minor change miraculously fixes it.

http://jsfiddle.net/x78hxxxy/

Backstory: I am populating an element with stringified JSON. In doing so, this breaks all the datalists I have throughout the form on the page, but ONLY ON CHROME.

This simplified fiddle shows that the datalist of the `<input>` does **not** work (the down arrow on the input shows that it indeed has a datalist, but nothing happens!)

Things that miraculously fix it:

- Not applying the JQuery `.html()` function (but I need to do that)
- Removing characters from the JSON (while still providing valid JSON... don't remove brackets, etc)
- Removing the `<form>` tags
- Removing the `<div>` tags
- Removing the lone second `<input>`
- Removing the whitespace from the `JSON.stringify()` function
- Not using Chrome (yeah, that's a long-term solution /s)

Things that don't fix it:

- Attempting to reapply the datalist with `$.  ...  .attr("list","mylist1")`
- Foregoing the JSON and applying the string directly: http://jsfiddle.net/x78hxxxy/1/
- EDIT: Using JQuery 2.x.x instead of 1.x.x
- EDIT: Converting double quotes to their HTML entity, thanks @charlietfl :)
- EDIT: Using pure Javascript (no JQuery!!!): jsfiddle.net/x78hxxxy/4/

I searched Chromium issues and couldn't find anything... what can of worms have I stumbled upon?

Comment: I also played with a variety of tweaks. Seems like a bug although technically double quotes are supposed to be converted to html entities `&quote;`.

Comment: Whew! At least I'm not the only one though, glad to know I'm not crazy. P.S. double quotes as their correct HTML entities does not improve the bug :)

Comment: what's strange is that commenting out the populating of the `<pre>` allows datalist to work even though the same json exists in the span

Comment: I have whittled down to a simplified example site that uses pure JS without any JSON, and the strange problem persists. I have gone ahead and submitted a Chromium issue, as I've eliminated all the other factors I can think of. Curiously, the length of the content is 1025 characters, at which point the datalist breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while ago, I had submitted this as a Chromium bug report, and it seems version 41.X of chrome (which is now stable) has solved this. There were other related issues, and the fix in version 41 seemed to fix most (if not all) of them.

The Chromium issue:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=445385